# Konjuktiv II Beispiel: "beginnen" oder "begonnen"?

Tags: subjunctive

Ich habe an einer Aufgabe gearbeitet und ich habe ein kleines Problem.

Ich verstehe die Aufgabe nicht.

Das ist mein Problem. Ich soll im folgenden Satz Konjuktiv II ausfüllen.

> Wenn ich noch einmal ***_*_** (beginnen konnen), ***_*_** (werden) ich sicher viele Fehler nicht mehr machen.

Den zweiten Teil verstehe ich, aber ich habe ein Problem mit dem ersten Teil.

Ich habe es so gemacht:

> Wenn ich noch einmal beg **o** nnen könnte, würde ich sicher viele Fehler nicht mehr machen.

Aber laut den Lösungen, schreibt man:

> Wenn ich noch einmal beg **i** nnen könnte, würde ich sicher viele Fehler nicht mehr machen.

Was ist mein Fehler? Was habe ich falsch gemacht?

Comment: http://verben.woxikon.de/verbformen/beginnen.php

Comment: The ge-form is only ever used with haben or sein... never with modals. There is no past tense in the first part, hence no haben/sein hence no ge-form but rather infinitive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Man muss nur "können" anpassen**, denn es ist das Verb. "Beginnen" bleibt im Infinitiv :

ich kann beginnen, ich konnte beginnen, ich hätte beginnen können, etc.

Und in deinem Fall : *ich könnte beginnen* (Konjunktiv II von "können")

**Die Konjugation von "beginnen" wäre :**

ich beginne, ich begann, ich beginne, etc.

*und im Konjunktiv II : ich begönne :*

*Wenn ich noch einmal begönne, würde ich sicher viele Fehler nicht mehr machen.*

Comment: Es wäre aber sehr ungewöhnlich, den Konjunktiv von _beginnen_ zu verwenden. Entweder nimmt man die Umschreibung mit _würde_ („Wenn ich noch einmal beginnen würde, …“) oder _anfangen_: „Wenn ich noch einmal anfinge/anfangen würde, …“

Comment: klar es wäre ungewöhnlich und ich habe sowas noch nie gehört, aber es wäre grammatikalisch richtig.

Comment: Habe ich auch nicht bestritten. :-) Es war nur eine Warnung an Deutschlerner, daß man mit einer solchen Konstruktion (außerhalb von Grammatikübungen) große Augen ernten wird.

Answer (score 3):

Mit den sogenannten Modalverben (können, müssen, dürfen etc.) bleibt das andere Verb im Infinitiv. Also bei Ihrer Aufgabe ist können das einzige Verb, das im Konjunktiv II konjugiert werden muss.